# Split text file into array using multiple delimiters

Tags: c#, text, split, edi

I have some 2k files to compare block by block, but these blocks identified differently.
What would be the best way to split each file into appropriate blocks list and then compare each block type to the same block type?

Block types:

- HL*
- EB*
- SE*
- GE*
- IEA*

Example of the file- I added spaces for better readability, but files have NO spaces.

```
    useless-Text-useless-Text-~
    useless-Text-useless-Text-useless-Text-~

    HL*Block1'HL'text-Block1'HL'text-Block1'HL'text-Block1'HL'text-~
    Block1'HL'text-Block1'HL'text-~

    HL*Block2'HL'text-Block2'HL'text-~
    Block2'HL'text-Block2'HL'text-~

    HL*Block3'HL'text-Block3'HL'text-Block3'HL'text-~
    Block3'HL'text-~

    EB*Block1'EB'Text-Block1'EB'Text-Block1'EB'Text-~
    Block1'EB'Text-Block1'EB'Text-~
    Block1'EB'Text-Block1'EB'Text-~

    EB*Block2'EB'Text-Block2'EB'Text-Block2'EB'Text-~
    Block2'EB'Text-Block2'EB'Text-~
    Block2'EB'Text-Block2'EB'Text-~

    EB*Block3'EB'Text-Block3'EB'Text-Block3'EB'Text-~
    Block3'EB'Text-Block3'EB'Text-~
    Block3'EB'Text-Block3'EB'Text-~

    EB*Block4'EB'Text-Block4'EB'Text-Block4'EB'Text-~
    Block4'EB'Text-Block4'EB'Text-~
    Block4'EB'Text-Block4'EB'Text-~

    EB*Block_N'EB'Text-Block_N'EB'Text-Block_N'EB'Text-~
    Block_N'EB'Text-Block_N'EB'Text-~
    Block_N'EB'Text-Block_N'EB'Text-~

    SE*Block1'SE'Text-Block1'SE'Text-~
    Block1'SE'Text-~

    GE*Block1'GE'Text-~
    IEA*Block1'IEA'Text-~
```

Comment: This is not validly formatted EDI. Your segment separator `~` is in the middle of each of your `EB` segments: is `Block1` supposed to be the name of a segment?

Comment: I assume the `~` is what he means by there are no spaces. Instead he has added this symbol to show that it joins onto the next line with no space.

Comment: @Doomsknight: He should clarify because I don't think that's a safe assumption. `~` is the typical segment separator in EDI; if it isn't the one here, then he isn't using one, which also makes this not valid. Likewise, `*` is the typical element separator, which he uses; but he also uses `'` as apparently another element separator -- further adding to the bizarre nature of this code.

Comment: Your right, he should clarify. :) It just seems odd that each `Text-` is followed by `Block`, except for the end of the lines. I can see why he has done it, but adding syntax to code can be very misleading.

Comment: which data you are actually want to extract?

Comment: @Andrew Please don't put the language in the question title; that's what tags are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up parsing text files from the bottom-up and added those sections into Lists

```
        List<String> listHL_Base = new List<String>();
        List<String> listEB_Base = new List<String>();
        List<String> listSE_Base = new List<String>();

        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(baseFile);
        string textBASE = streamReader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
        streamReader.Close();

        //we start scanning file from the button to up)           
        string[] textBASE_Step1 = Regex.Split(textBASE, "GE\\*");
        textBASE = textBASE_Step1[0];

        string[] textBASE_Step2 = Regex.Split(textBASE, "SE\\*");
        for (int i = 1; i < textBASE_Step2.Length; i++) //creating list with SE values
        {
            listSE_Base.Add(textBASE_Step2[i]);
        }

        textBASE = textBASE_Step2[0]; //remainder (beginning) of the file, without GE, or SE. Only  EB's and HL's Left
        string[] textBASE_Step3 = Regex.Split(textBASE, "EB\\*");
        for (int i = 1; i < textBASE_Step3.Length; i++) //creating list with EB values
        {
            listEB_Base.Add(textBASE_Step3[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can identify or know the patterns then the best approach is to use regular expressions.
There are many tutorials around, have a look at [Parse Text Files With Regular Expressions](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2004/11/01/parse-text-files-with-regular-expressions.aspx).

Comment: +1. Here is a good link, that will find and add all the blocks into an array. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx  (you will need an approriate Regex)

Comment: @Doomsknight When you say "+1", shouldn't you actually vote up the answer then?

Comment: Woops thought I had ;) Have a cold, and very exhausted. :p My bad. +1 now added.